# What is wrong with the below PostgreSql insert function.. throwing error

Tags: postgresql

I have written a function in PostgreSQL which accepts two parameters viz varchar and int .
The aim is to insert record

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fnInsert(varchar,int) RETURNS void AS   
'BEGIN
        Insert Into testtable(col1,col2) values ($1,$2)
RETURN;
END;'
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But while trying to compile it is throwing error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "RETURN"
LINE 4: RETURN;
        ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "RETURN"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 173
```

If I take out the RETURN statement, I am getting the below error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "END"
LINE 4: END;'
        ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "END"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 173
```

Please help me in identifying what is wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably complaining about the lack of semicolon after

```
Insert Into testtable(col1,col2) values ($1,$2)
```

Comment: Yes u r absolutely right. thanks a lot.. i will select ur answer after 8 minutes